# No output while plotting HeatMap using Rcharts

Tags: r, rcharts

I am plotting heatmap using rcharts using following code.

```
a<-as.list(c(22,13,25,43,63,47,42,43,42,75))
b<-as.list(c(12,32,15,41,61,71,45,23,22,45))
c<-as.list(c(1,1,1,1,3,1,5,6,7,3))


a<-data$V1
b<-data$V2
c<-data$V3

library(RCurl)
require(devtools)
library(rCharts)
h <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
h$chart(
        animation=FALSE,
        plotBorderWidth=3, 
        type='line',
        renderTo = "snipa-raplot-dynamic"       
       )
h$chart(margin = list(left =0))
xAxistmp <- list()
#labels=list(style=c(fontSize="15px"))
xAxistmp[[1]] <- list()

h$xAxis(xAxistmp)

yAxistmp <- list()

yAxistmp[[1]] <- list()


h$yAxis(yAxistmp)               
seriestmp<-list()
seriestmp[[1]]<-list(data = cbind(a,b,c), type="heatmap")
#seriestmp[[2]]<-list(data = b, type="column", name="Common",color='green')
#seriestmp[[3]]<-list(data = c, type="column", name="1000 Genome")
h$series(seriestmp)
h$save('C:/Users/man4ish/Desktop/barplot.html', standalone = TRUE)
```

But there is no output. Also i could not find the way to debug the issue as it is wrapper to highcharts where i can generate the heatmap using similar logic. Pls help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add extra javascript libraries to get the heatmap using RCharts. You can do that by adding:

```
h$addAssets(js = c("https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js",
                   "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"))
```

Also your data is in the wrong format. You need to remove the column names of the matrix to get the right JSON output. The first column of the matrix is the x axis coordinate, the second column is the y axis coordinate and the third column is the value of the heatmap square.

Couldn't figure out what your values where so here is an example:

```
 library(rCharts)
 a<-as.list(c(0,0,1,1))
 b<-as.list(c(0,1,0,1))
 c<-as.list(c(2,3,4,5))

df <- cbind(a,b,c)
colnames(df) <-NULL


h <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
h$addAssets(js = c("https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js",
                   "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"))

h$chart(type='heatmap')
h$xAxis(categories=list(c(0,1)))
h$yAxis(categories=list(c(0,1)))
h$addParams(colorAxis=list(min=0,minColor='#FFFFFF',maxColor="#!Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]!#"))
h$series(data = df)
h
```

Comment: It works fine for me but when i use this list long list it does not work for me. http://www.filedropper.com/file_4

Comment: In your list, x and y don't start at 0 and you have some missing values, for ex, no value for `(6135001, 6135000)`.

Comment: I changed values to  h$xAxis(categories=list(c(6135001, 6135015)))
and h$yAxis(categories=list(c(6135001, 6135015)))  still no output.

Comment: Pls help me as i am in great need.  Thanks

Comment: I could generate output but when i use many points almost more than 15000 points, It takes very long to update browser and finally i see no output.